# From stata to R: t test with condition

Tags: r

I have the following ttest in stata

```
ttest ts_lostr=ts_histr if elq1==1, unp une
```

I don't know how to translate this in R:

this is obviously wrong `if(elq1==1) {t.test(ts_lostr, ts_histr)}`

How do I tell R to do the t test only when the value of "elq1" is equal to one?

Comment: The 'if' function is not vectorized and is not used for selection. If you have a dataframe then you can use subset to pare down the rows and then perhaps use 'with' to set up a call to t.test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps (assuming you have a dataframe named 'dfrm' with columns 'elq1', 'ts_lostr', 'ts_histr'):

```
with( subset( dfrm, elq1==1), 
           t.test( ts_lostr, ts_histr) )
```

If this is a paired t-test then you need to set the correct parameter. Do read the worked examples on the help page.

Comment: and to apply "robust" as here? `reg testscr str, vce(r)` (testscr and str are both variables in the same dataset)

Comment: You shouldn't assume that offering Stata  code will do a good job of communicating algorithms to R users.suggest you read '?r.test' to see what options are most satisfactory. I'm guessing this isn't actually about t.test but is really about regression and the is an entire Task View about Robust Metods.